# How do I skip tests for the "compile" and "install" target only but not the "test" target?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, netbeans

I have a situation where our unit tests take a long time to execute for our business domain project as it sets up a database to a known state then proceeds to execute each step. I understand this can be done with "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" on the command line but wish to configure this within NetBeans for the project only, globally would be acceptable if anyone could clarify how to configure within the IDE.

How can I configure maven2 to only execute tests when the "test" target is called?

Using the following will disable tests even when the "test" target is called ([from the maven docos](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test)).

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I must apologise, I have now found how to do this. For anyone else looking for this NetBeans > Preferences > Miscellaneous > Maven. There's a button "Edit Global Custom Goal Definitions", this will bring up a dialog where you can specify a custom name, goals to run and any -D properties to execute the goal with, now you will have "Custom" under your right-click menu on the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test

Just specify -Dmaven.test.skip=true when you invoke a target and don't want to execute tests.

Comment: Thank you Kyle, sorry I should have mentioned from my IDE (NetBeans)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that simply in project properties.
In NetBeans go to Project Properties, in right column select Actions. Here you can set properirtes for every action and every configuration (enviroment).

To skip tests add properties **maven.test.skip=true**

Answer (score 4):

Updating for Netbeans 8:

- Right click on your project
- Select properties
- Go to Actions
- Select a Maven action
- Add the Skip Tests property

See the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see you've accepted an answer on this, but let me suggest an alternative.

The kind of test you're describing is an integration test... not a unit test. True, it's still an automated test, but it relies on an external resource and can take significantly longer to run. That's the earmark of an IT.

Maven is built to run integration tests separately for the very reasons you describe. The [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) is used for executing integration tests (*IT.java instead of *Test.java), and that plugin executes during the *integration-test* lifecycle phase (whereas surefire hooks the *test* phase).

Bottom line is that you can run all the way up to the *package* [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) without executing the longer-running tests.

Note that the *install* phase comes after *integration-test*, and that makes sense... if you're installing a new snapshot, you verify likely want to run your full test suite to ensure everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

on a project basis, the best way is to disable test execution by default and create a profile that enables it. Then in netbeans UI, open project properties Action panel and in the test, test file and debug test actions enable the profile.